# Xpath targeting website text

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to set my xpath to only target a pages text content, however a section below the article 'about the author' keeps getting included, I would like xpath that targets the articles text only + the title.

***my xpath so far:***

```
//*[@class="content"]//p[not(contains(@id, "author-bio"))] |
//*[@id="content_wrapper"]//h1
```

This works but does not remove the about the author section as expected. I am working off the below article.

http://www.intomobile.com/2013/11/05/samsung-galaxy-s3-android-43-update-rolling-out-international-users/

I am using the firepath extension to firefox/firebug which lets me view the elements i am targeting.

Answer (score 1):

That particular document is XHTML, and it has a root element of

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

The `xmlns="..."` means that the `html` element (and all its un-prefixed descendants) are in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.  Now un-prefixed names in XPath expressions refer to nodes that are *not* in a namespace, so

```
//p[not(contains(@id, "author-bio"))]
```

is looking for an element named `p` in no namespace, and won't match an element named `p` in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.

The correct approach would be to map a prefix to that namespace URI and use the prefix in the XPath expressions, e.g.

```
//xhtml:p[not(contains(@id, "author-bio"))]
```

but exactly how you define the prefix mappings depends on the XPath engine you're using.  If your tool doesn't provide a way to do prefix mappings then you'll have to use predicates on the `local-name()`, e.g.

```
//*[local-name() = 'p'][not(contains(@id, "author-bio"))]
```

The same applies to the `h1`, you need to either bind and use a prefix or use the `*[local-name() = 'h1']` trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I played about with your ideas but none seemed to work, still the about me is being targeted.

Comment: Or if you have XPath 2, you can use `//*:h1` instead the local-name trick

Answer (score 0):

id('home_right_column')//p[not(ancestor::*[@id= 'author-bio'])] | //*[@id="content_wrapper"]//h1

Got it myself :)